# Trigger with SELECT from same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to build a trigger that takes the minimum price for a book and is triggered if the new price is 5 times the minimum value. I get an error for my SELECT statement. I think it is because I am selecting from the same table the trigger was fired.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON book_type
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE 
newPrice number;
lowestPrice number;
topPrice number;

BEGIN
newPrice := NEW.price;
lowestPrice := (SELECT MIN(price) FROM book_type);
topPrice := (5 * lowestPrice); 

IF (topPrice < newPrice) THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Error. Price too high.');
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Generally, a trigger would not be the most appropriate way to solve this sort of problem.  If it is a homework assignment where a trigger is required, have you learned about compound triggers?  If you want a single non-compound trigger, you'd probably need a statement level trigger which would be less efficient than multiple triggers (or a compound trigger) but would be a lot less complicated.

Comment: The error is: encountered the symbol "select" when expecting one of the following: ( + ;

Comment: You can't modify data by trigger in the same table modification to which caused trigger to fire. Oracle will not allow that - ORA-4091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't assign a value that way.  You'd need something like:

```
select min(price) into lowestPrice from book_type;
```

However, the next problem you'll see is a Mutating Table error (ORA-4091), because you're attempting a select from the same table the trigger is defined for.  In other words, the trigger is defined on table book_type, and you're trying to select from table book_type in your trigger.  Oracle does not allow this on statement triggers.

Finally, dbms_output isn't terribly useful in a trigger, because there's no terminal to display your output to.  Generally, you'd raise an exception instead.

Comment: I made the changes and raised an exception like you suggested but I do not get a Mutating Table Error. My trigger works perfectly now. Maybe it's because my trigger is executed before the insert or update so there are no changes made to the table until my trigger tests pass.(?)